# Docusign void envelopes and send reminder functionality

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to integrate docusign in our application, I am using a developer account to go through the various funtionalities. Is there an endpoint for voiding envelopes and sending reminders to various recipients for a particular envelope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two different things.

Voiding - https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-common-api-tasks-void-an-envelope the endpoint is the [UpdateEnvelope](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/update?_gl=1*1cl7fad*_ga*MTk2MjgwNDgxNS4xNjIyNjU1ODc5*_ga_1TZ7S9D6BQ*MTYzOTM0NTgzMC4xNjIuMC4xNjM5MzQ1ODMxLjA.&_ga=2.131829260.2063251623.1639345830-1962804815.1622655879) endpoint but you have to provide voidReason in the JSON in addition to change to status to **voided** like this:

```
{
  "status": "voided",
  "voidedReason": "The reason for voiding the envelope"
}
```

Sending reminders. This can be done ahead of time, [on a schedule](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-common-api-tasks-add-reminders-and-expiration-to-an-envelope), or ad-hoc.
Ad-hoc I assume is was you had in mind, so in theory, you can make an empty update to an envelope with the option to **resend_envelope=true** option. That will just send it again, not sure if you consider that a reminder or not.

Comment: Thank you so much I will be looking into it right away